# Really weird peaks when profiling a simple scene with Unity3D

Tags: android, unity, optimization

I need some help optimizing my game. I have spent last 3 days digging around with no luck. I have noticed really odd results in the unity profiler so, I have created a simple scene with just a cube and a camera, and again, really odd results. Could anybody have a look at this screenshots?:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You will see some significant peaks that make the frame time too high (30fps sometime or less). Scene hasn't any script, no coliders, no rigid bodies (notice the Physics simulate % in one of the shots).

Could anybody explain what is happening?

PD. Target platform is Android. This are taken from a Nexus 4 device.
PD2. Somebody can argue that this is not a real scenario, but I have had this problems in a real game myself and wanted to show a simple example to expose the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future reference, Win7 comes with a nice Snipping tool for capturing just a portion of the screen. Further, it looks like rendering stuff. Does it only happen on one machine? Have anything else running?

Comment: No, I don't have anything more running on the machine. I have tried with 2 different android devices with same results (I get occasional peaks). What do you mean by "it looks like rendering stuff"? With just a cube  on the screen and no other client logic running do you think it is ok to have these peaks ruining a constant frame rate?. On the other hand, sorry for the screenshots issue.

Answer (score 1):

For What i can see :

- You have some shader taking a lot of resources, do you have a custom shader?
- you have a peak related to WaitForTargetFrameRate this looks a lot
  like a VSynch issue i had before, try disabling VSynch and you should
  get some relief already

Vsync can be disabled in [Quality Settings](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-QualitySettings.html)